# How to update constrain when textField have input text

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, constraints

I have a question right now. I have a textField, a tableView and a label. When textField text is empty,the tableView is hidden.But when user input something in textField, the list of tableView will show on the View. TableView's position is between textField and label. How to update this constrain? I try to do this, but it doesn't work for me. Thanks.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

var tableView: UITableView = UITableView()
var textField: UITextField = UITextField()
var label:UILabel = UILabel()
var haveText:Bool = false

var autoCompletePossibilities = ["Wand","Wizard","Test","1","12","123","1234","12345"]
var autoComplete = [String]()

var tableviewHeightConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint?

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    loadContent()

}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    loadVFL()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    textField.delegate = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
    label.text = "hello I'm beginner.Nice."

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func DictionaryOfInstanceVariables(_ container:AnyObject, objects: String ...) -> [String:AnyObject] {
    var views = [String:AnyObject]()
    for objectName in objects {
        guard let object = object_getIvar(container, class_getInstanceVariable(type(of: container), objectName)) else {
            assertionFailure("\(objectName) is not an ivar of: \(container)");
            continue
        }
        views[objectName] = object as AnyObject?
    }
    return views
}

func loadContent() {

    view.addSubview(textField)
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    view.addSubview(label)
}

func loadVFL() {

    let views = DictionaryOfInstanceVariables(self, objects:
        "textField"
        ,"label"
        ,"tableView"
    )

    let metrics = ["padding":15]

    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[textField]|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[label]|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
    self.view.addConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[tableView]|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))

    //declare tableview height constraints and init here
    tableviewHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: view,
                                                        attribute: .height,
                                                        relatedBy: .equal,
                                                        toItem: nil,
                                                        attribute: .notAnAttribute,
                                                        multiplier: 1,
                                                        constant: 0) // init it with a 0 height
    tableView.addConstraint(tableviewHeightConstraint!) // add the constraint to the tableView
    self.view.addConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-50-[textField(60.0)][tableView][label(30.0)]", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    let index = indexPath.row as Int

    cell.textLabel?.text = autoComplete[index]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return autoComplete.count
}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    tableviewHeightConstraint?.constant = 160; // required height
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { // animate so it will be pretty
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    return true
}

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let subString = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

    searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubString(subString: subString)

    return true
}

func searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubString(subString:String)
{

    autoComplete.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

    for key in autoCompletePossibilities {

        let myString:NSString = key as NSString

        let subStringRange:NSRange = myString.range(of: subString)

        if subStringRange.location == 0 {

            autoComplete.append(key)
        }
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

log print:

```
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(

"NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009be40 V:[UITextField:0x7fc04db09e10]-(0)-[UITableView:0x7fc04e81e400]   (active)",

"NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009bf30 UITableView:0x7fc04e81e400.height == 150   (active)",

"NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009d4c0 V:[UITableView:0x7fc04e81e400]-(0)-[UILabel:0x7fc04be057c0'hello I'm beginner.Nice.']   (active)",

"NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000281360 V:[UITextField:0x7fc04db09e10]-(0)-[UILabel:0x7fc04be057c0'hello I'm beginner.Nice.']   (active)"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800009d4c0 V:[UITableView:0x7fc04e81e400]-(0)-[UILabel:0x7fc04be057c0'hello I'm beginner.Nice.']   (active)
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

2017.06.16 UPdate new crash log:

[crash log here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxHE3.png)

2017.06.16 Finally successful code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

var tableView: UITableView = UITableView()
var textField: UITextField = UITextField()
var label:UILabel = UILabel()
var haveText:Bool = false

var autoCompletePossibilities = ["Wand","Wizard","Test","1","12","123","1234","12345"]
var autoComplete = [String]()

var tableviewHeightConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint?

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    loadContent()
    loadVFL()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    textField.delegate = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
    label.text = "hello I'm beginner.Nice."

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func DictionaryOfInstanceVariables(_ container:AnyObject, objects: String ...) -> [String:AnyObject] {
    var views = [String:AnyObject]()
    for objectName in objects {
        guard let object = object_getIvar(container, class_getInstanceVariable(type(of: container), objectName)) else {
            assertionFailure("\(objectName) is not an ivar of: \(container)");
            continue
        }
        views[objectName] = object as AnyObject?
    }
    return views
}

func loadContent() {

    view.addSubview(textField)
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    view.addSubview(label)
}

func loadVFL() {

    let views = DictionaryOfInstanceVariables(self, objects:
        "textField"
        ,"label"
        ,"tableView"
    )

    let metrics = ["padding":15]

    tableviewHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: tableView,
                                                        attribute: .height,
                                                        relatedBy: .equal,
                                                        toItem: nil,
                                                        attribute: .height,
                                                        multiplier: 1,
                                                        constant: 0) // init it with a 0 height
    tableView.addConstraint(tableviewHeightConstraint!) // add the constraint to the tableView

    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[textField]|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[label]|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[tableView]|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-50.0-[textField(60.0)][tableView][label(30.0)]", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    let index = indexPath.row as Int

    cell.textLabel?.text = autoComplete[index]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return autoComplete.count
}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    super.updateViewConstraints()

    tableView.removeConstraints(tableView.constraints)
    tableviewHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal , toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 160.0)
    tableView.addConstraint(tableviewHeightConstraint!) // add the constraint to the tableView

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { // animate so it will be pretty
        self.updateViewConstraints()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    return true
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    super.updateViewConstraints()

    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    tableView.removeConstraints(tableView.constraints)
    tableviewHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal , toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0.0)
    tableView.addConstraint(tableviewHeightConstraint!) // add the constraint to the tableView

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { // animate so it will be pretty
        self.updateViewConstraints()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    return true
}

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let subString = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

    searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubString(subString: subString)

    return true
}

func searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubString(subString:String)
{

    autoComplete.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

    for key in autoCompletePossibilities {

        let myString:NSString = key as NSString

        let subStringRange:NSRange = myString.range(of: subString)

        if subStringRange.location == 0 {

            autoComplete.append(key)
        }
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

[(IMAGE) Finally View like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Dv6Y.png)

Comment: have you seen any errors on the console?

Comment: update my question.

Comment: oh conflicting constraints. I think you shouldn't put your constraints on this `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` instead load it in the `loadVFL` method. manipulate UITableView height instead

Comment: I got it. I fix this issue. Thank you @Joshua . You are so nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach will be loading all the needed constraints on `loadVFL`.

```
func loadVFL() {

    let views = DictionaryOfInstanceVariables(self, objects:
         "textField"
        ,"tableView"
        ,"label"
    )

    let metrics = ["padding":15]
    self.view.addConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[textField]|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
    self.view.addConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[tableView]|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
    self.view.addConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[label]|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))

//declare tableview height constraints and init here
  tableviewHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: tableView,
                                               attribute: .height,
                                               relatedBy: .equal,
                                               toItem: nil,
                                               attribute: .notAnAttribute,
                                               multiplier: 1,
                                               constant: 0) // init it with a 0 height
    tableView.addConstraint(tableviewHeightConstraint) // add the constraint to the tableView
    self.view.addConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-50-[textField(60.0)][tableView][label(30.0)]", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
}
```

After initialising in your `textShouldBeginEditing` function activate your tableview constraint:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
      tableviewHeightConstraint.constant = 160; // required height
      UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { // animate so it will be pretty
          self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
      }
      return true
}
```

If you want to hide to it on some function you call when you are done searching. Just set the constant back to 0

I think that should work. Give it a try and let me know

Comment: Thanks your answer. Is tableviewHeightConstraint  NSLayoutConstraint?. I declear that "var tableviewHeightConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint?" And then it crash. I update question about my crash log.

Comment: so what is the crash log?

Comment: what did you do? it seems that you added the height to the view instead of the tableView?

Comment: ohh got it. you just copied my answer without checking the item I was passing is correct. updated. basically, the tableViewheight constrait's item should refer to the tableView. can you try it again. sorry about that @please_tolerate_my_stupid_ques let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks your advice.Help me a lot. I take your concept to try it and it work successful. But my textField top constrain V:|-50.0-  looks like dissapear. it's weird.

Comment: glad it worked. for that issue always consult your console for the logs it shows the breaking constraints. if it cannot satisfy try to use priorities